# How do I execute a complex shell find command from Python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a complex shell command from inside of python. The naive attempt:

```
subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec touch {} \;"], cwd=".")
```

is failing. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec", "touch", "{}", ";"])
```

cwd="." Is not needed as it is the default.

Comment: Defaulting to "." is an extension (I think it is a GNU extension). [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/find.html) requires a path in the command line.