# Why does subprocess.Popen not work with find -exec?

Tags: python, subprocess

I currently have the following:

```
subprocess.Popen(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c",
    "\"echo 'this will not echo'; touch testing.txt \"", ";"], shell=True)
```

Which does not appear to work (no testing.txt file is generated or output from the echo statement).

Would the above command actually work fine using `subprocess.Popen`? I'll need to do some debugging if so...

I'm essentially trying to run:

```
find . -exec sh -c "echo 'test'; touch abcxyz" \;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does it work if you add `shell=True` to the `Popen` call? Or perhaps it's enough to remove the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Does the command 
find one_directory -type f -iname '*.json' -exec sh -c sed 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g' {} >> import.json; echo '' >> import.json ; 
works in a shell?

Comment: The semicolon is required for `find`. And yes the bash one liner works in shell.

Comment: Adding `shell=True` does not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: An alternative (using subprocess.call): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796444/1663462

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

`subprocess.Popen(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c", "echo 'this will not echo'; touch testing.txt ", ";"])`

Removed `shell=True`.